# A reference for the equality $|G:H| = \sum_i \dim(V_i)\dim(V_i^H)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup.
Let $V_1, \dots , V_r$ be (equivalence class representatives for) the irreducible complex representations of $G$. Let the stabilizer subspace $V_i^H =  \{ v \in V_i \ | \ hv=v \ , \forall h \in H  \}$

What is a reference for the following equality? $$|G:H| = \sum_i \dim(V_i)\dim(V_i^H)$$

If you know a proof but not a reference, then you can post it, your answer will be a reference.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it should follow just by inducing the trivial representation of $H$ to $G$ and describing the dimension of this in two ways, but I will need a pen to write out the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So expanding on my comment, let $1_H^G$ denote the trivial representation of $H$ induced to $G$ which clearly has dimension $|G:H|$.

On the other hand, denoting by $[V,W]_K$ the usual normalized inner product of representations of the group $K$ the dimension is also (by Frobenius reciprocity) $$\sum_{i=1}\dim(V_i)[V_i,1_H^G]_G = \sum_i\dim(V_i)[V_i,1_H]_H = \sum_i\dim(V_i)\dim(V_i^H)$$

Comment: Can you give more details about the Frobenius reciprocity and the equality $[V_i,1_H^G]_G = [V_i,1_H]_H$?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux That equality is precisely Frobenius reciprocity as it is usually stated for characters, since the inner product counts multiplicities due to the irreducibles forming an orthonormal basis, and the multiplies are also given as the dimensions of homomorphism spaces since everything is semisimple.

Comment: Do you know a reference where the proof you suggested appear?

Comment: @Sebastien This should be covered in most introductory books on the subject, such as James-Liebeck or Isaacs. It might also be in Fulton-Harris.

Comment: I'm not asking about Frobenius reciprocity, but about your answer (I found nothing analogous in Isaacs' book).

Comment: Which part of it? I am fairly certain the steps themselves should be covered in those books, though probably not this specific result. The one thing I suppose might tend to get left out is the identification between Hom's from the trivial module and fixed points.

Comment: The same argument, but without the use of characters: Let $A = K\left[G\right]$. The Artin-Wedderburn theorem yields that $A \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \left(V_i\right)^{\oplus \dim\left(V_i\right)}$ as left $A$-modules. Hence, $A^H \cong \left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^r \left(V_i\right)^{\oplus \dim\left(V_i\right)}\right)^H \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \left(V_i^H\right)^{\oplus \dim\left(V_i\right)}$ as vector spaces (since the operation of taking $H$-fixed points commutes with direct sums). Taking dimensions on both sides of this isomorphism, we obtain ...

Comment: ... the equality $\dim \left(A^H\right) = \sum_{i=1}^r \dim\left(V_i\right) \dim\left(V_i^H\right)$. Now, it remains to prove that $\dim \left(A^H\right) = \left[G : H\right]$ (where $\left[G : H\right]$ is my notation for what you call $\left|G : H\right|$). But this is easy: Just observe that $\left(\sum_{g \in K} g\right)_{K \in H \backslash G}$ is a basis of the vector space $A^H$, where we regard $H \backslash G$ as the set of all right cosets of $H$ in $G$ (that is, subsets of $G$ having the form $Hk$ for some $k \in G$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Is it usual to talk about the inner product of representations? The characters form a vector space, but the representations form a category. So in a strict use of the language, it is correct to talk about inner product of characters (or even, of equivalence class representatives of representations). Then, is it an acceptable *abuse of language* (in a published paper) to write "inner product of representations"?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Good question. I have not really thought about it, but in this context, I would certainly find it fine.